# How to build android AOSP to a specific target product

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to generate a rom to install in my phone which is a Motorola 1Gen Codename **Falcon**. I have followed both instructions from the official tutorial on source.android.com and also [this tutorial](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2364970).
Summing up what I did:

- set up the build environment
- Get the AOSP source:

> repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
>   repo sync

- Get the device tree and kernel for Falcon:

> git clone github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_motorola_falcon -b cm-14.1 device/motorola/falcon
>   git clone github.com/CyanogenMod/android_kernel_motorola_msm8226 -b cm-14.1 kernel/motorola/msm8226

(I removed the https:// because my account can only post two links)

- Defined the target architecture:

> . build/envsetup.sh
>   lunch aosp_arm-eng

- and finally build it:

> make -j8

Accordin to this tutorial from xda-developers I posted, after the successful build, it was going to create a .zip file to be flashed at **out/target/product/*CODENAME***. But it created only a **out/target/product/generic** with a **system.img** file and not a **out/target/product/falcon** as I expected (was my expectation right?).

So anyway, did I miss something important in the process of making it? How to correctly make for my target? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Cyanogenmod is no longer actively developed or supported.  It has become LineageOS, so your best bet is to look there.  Building Cyanogenmod (or LineageOS) is slightly different than what is described on AOSP.  Look here for specific instructions for the Moto G: https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/falcon/build

Comment: Just FWIW, AOSP is missing a tremendous amount of the code that is essential to customize it for a specific device.  Even if you are building for one of the supported devices (probably a Nexus) there is still proprietary code that you have to get, somehow. Sometimes you can get the code from an existing device.  ... or maybe, as Larry says, Lineage will work.  Either way, this is likely to take a while...

Answer (score 0):

You're intentionally building for `generic`, though you're not aware of. `lunch aosp_arm-eng` sets the target. `aosp_arm-eng` is not the falcon you want to build for, it's the very `generic`.

To build for falcon, pick the *correct* item from `lunch` menu.

Answer (score 0):

If the Target Platform suffix is what you are looking for, then there are two solutions:

1. Using a separate output directory:

   $> export OUT_DIR=out_armv7

   This will override the default out/ directory for your target binary.
2. Searching in the out/snoog/ directory (Android > 7.0) and find Target Platform specific .mk file, e.g. Android-asop_arm.mk